# NPM conditional script (Windows / Mac) shall execute different commands)

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-scripts

**Use case:**

I am setting up a `prepublishOnly` hook in NPM which deletes the "lib" folder, then transpiles the typescript source files into a new lib folder and then it does run the test.

**The problem:**

Two persons are supposed to publish the NPM packages, both working on different OS (Windows / Mac). Therefore the commands for deleting the folders are different.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf lib",
    "clean:windows": "if exist lib rmdir /s /q lib",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json --format stylish src/**/*.ts",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.ts\""
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-push": "npm run clean:windows && npm run build && npm run test"
    }
  },
```

**The question:**

Is there a way to run NPM scripts conditionally (based on the used OS) or is there a remove folder command which works across these OS?

Comment: You may also want to take a look into ShellJS where you can use JavaScript functions which wrap the common shell commands in an OS specific way and you can just invoke `node script.js` to run the ShellJS commands.

Comment: @TomasHübelbauer - yes utilizing shelljs is more appropriate than using _gulp_ for this kind of task. I've posted an answer to provide further detail of what you were suggesting in your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding *gulp* to your list of tools seems rather unnecessary if all you want to do is delete a folder(s) via an npm script in a cross-platform way. For a lightweight solution consider the following two solutions instead:

---

#### Solution 1

Take a look at [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf), it's described as:

> The UNIX command `rm -rf` for node.

**Usage**

1. `cd` to your project directory and run the following command:

   ```
   npm install rimraf --save-dev
   ```
2. Change your `clean` script in `package.json` to the following:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "clean": "rimraf lib",
     ...
   },
   ```
3. Delete the `clean:windows` script from your `package.json` as that's now redundant.

**Note** I've not had great success with it when installing it as a local dependency, hence I use solution two below. However you may have greater success - so it's worth a try.

---

#### Solution 2

The following solution utilizes the `shelljs` [`rm`](http://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#rmoptions-file--file-) command which is analogous to the Unix [`rm -rf`](https://ss64.com/bash/rm.html) command except it's for node - hence it's a cross platform equivalent.

The following steps shows how this can be achieved:

1. `cd` to your project directory and install [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) by running the following command:

   ```
   npm install shelljs --save-dev
   ```
2. Create a custom node script as follows, let's name the file `clean.js`:

   ```js
   const shell = require('shelljs');

   process.argv.slice(2).forEach(function(_path) {
     shell.rm('-rf', _path);
   });
   ```

   and save it to a hidden directory called `.scripts` in the projects root directory. For example:

   ```
   .
   ├── .scripts
   │   └── clean.js
   ├── lib
   │   └── ...
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   ├── package.json
   ├── src
   │   └── ...
   └── ...
   ```
3. Replace your `clean` script in `package.json` to the following:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "clean": "node .scripts/clean lib",
     ...
   },
   ```

   You can also pass multiple path arguments to `clean.js` too. For example:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "clean": "node .scripts/clean lib another/folder/path foo/bar",
     ...
   },
   ```

   Filepaths are handled too. For example:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "clean": "node .scripts/clean path/to/quux.js",
     ...
   },
   ```
4. Delete the `clean:windows` script from your `package.json` as that's now redundant.

**Notes**

1. `clean.js` utilizes nodes built-in [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to obtain an array of command line arguments passed to Node when the script was invoked.
2. We then [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array of arguments from index `2` to ensure that we only include the folder/file path arguments (e.g. `lib`).
3. Finally we loop over each folder path in the array using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and invoke `shell.rm('-rf', _path);` in each turn of the loop to delete the asset.

---

#### Edit / Update:

An alternative cross-platform solution, (which wasn't available when originally posting this answer), is to utilize the [shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx) package, which is described as:

> `shx` is a wrapper around [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) Unix commands, providing an easy solution for simple Unix-like, cross-platform commands in npm package scripts

1. Run the following command to install `shx`:

   ```
   npm i -D shx
   ```
2. Then redefine your `clean` script in `package.json` as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "clean": "shx rm -rf lib"
   }
   ```

Comment: I use shx, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I fix issues like this is to use `gulp` to define a set of os-specific tasks because the code you write there is OS-agnostic.

You will need to install gulp as a dependency and create a `gulpfile.js` in the root directory.
In it, define a task to delete the folder.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs-extra');

const rootFolder = path.join(__dirname);
const libFolder = path.join(rootFolder, 'lib');

gulp.task('clean:lib', function () {
  return deleteFolder(libFolder);
});

function deleteFolder(folder) {
  return fs.removeSync(folder);
}

gulp.task('deleteLib', ['clean:lib']);
```

Then, in your `package.json` script, you can then do `&& gulp deleteLib`.
(*Make sure that the used packages in your gulpfile are installed as a dev-dependency in your package.json!*)

Code is untested and written at the top of my head, but it's just to give you a general idea.

Comment: Alright makes sense to use gulp then, I always tried to avoid that but I have no better idea either at the moment :).